# Only changing series that are visible in Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, highcharts

I have a spline chart with 10 different curves on it - when you visit page, no charts are visible as I have "visible" = false. The user then clicks on which curve(s) they wish to see.

I want to be able to dynamically change the data with a button and also change it back to the original state. However, I only want to target a series that a user has clicked on and thus has set as "visible".

```
// the button action
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4], false);

});

$('#addNew').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#container').highcharts().redraw();
});
```

If it makes any difference, I'm using django to implement this.

Comment: so basically if a user is viewing one series, and he clicks on the button the data for that series should change and it should be visible, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically change only visible series you can check if `visible` property of series is set to true.

```
$('#updateVisibleSeries').click(function(){
    Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(s){
    if(s.visible === true) {
        s.addPoint(42, false);
    }
    chart.redraw();
  })
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5nccnqc9/